# dwa - 171 AC thumb drive wireless network device

Tags: hardware

I am new to Linux.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 desktop ...

It didn't discover my DLink DWA-171 AC thumb drive wireless network device ...

The dlink site shows a Linux driver download for this device but it will not come up to let you download it.

Where can I search for the driver and how would I go about installing it ?

Larry

Comment: Please post the relevant `lsusb` result. DWA-171 has at least two different versions (revisions) with entirely different chipsets.

Comment: Help me out here Michael ... What is Isusb ?

Comment: Open the Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), type `lsusb` then Enter. It will list all USB devices including the WiFi and it will show the exact chipset. We need the line regarding WiFi only.

Comment: Many Thanks for the explanation ... In the meantime I installed an older USB device and it did finally find it ... I also installed a network card in the system and plugged in an Ethernet cable ...

Comment: I am going to go with the Ethernet cable for the time being so that I can learn a few things before I disconnect it and try to connect with the USB Device ( Broadcom 4326U ) ... It is a Linksys WUSB54GSC v2 802.11g Adapter ...

Comment: For Broadcom use this answer as a guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: Dlink official site has the download option working now. Try with some other system. And if your device is C1, the driver is for Linux Kernel <=5 and will NOT work in x64 devices